# Joining sections (Channel) to query based on a related item attribute

Tags: entries, categories, mysql, query, elementquery

I've been trying this for a while now, so might have read this before. Sorry about that, I'm struggling really hard to get this right. At first I tried (wrongly) with the eager load features.

I have two channels: `events` and `shows`. In the `events` you can select a `show` with an entry field. The shows items have a category attached. I need to filter the `events`, based on the category of the `show`

Like `events with shows where show has category 1`. They told me on the slack channel to join the tables I needed, but cannot manage to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about doing this in a single query. Referencing this doc page section, https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/relations.html#templating, you can make use of `relatedTo()` by passing in IDs.

Assuming you know the ID of the category already and that ID is `1`:

```
{% set showIds = craft.entries.section('shows').relatedTo(1).ids() %}

{% set entries = craft.entries.section('events').relatedTo(showIds).all() %}
```

The `relatedTo()` method doesn't care if the IDs are from Entries or Categories, or even Users and Tags. They're all Elements stored in the `elements` table so they have unique IDs.

Comment: Yes, I went for this solution also, is the less hacky I've found so far. I still think there should be a way to join, but for now I managed doing something like that.